# continuity of a piece wise function defined partially on a closed interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

using epsilon delta definition prove that $f(x)=\left \{
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & : x \in[0,1]\\
1 & :  x=-1
\end{array}\right.$ is continuous on $E= [0,1] \cup \{-1\}$.

Here is my attempt. I want to show first that f is continuous at -1 and then show that it is continuous at every point of $[0,1]$. f is cont at -1 if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, I want to find a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x \in E$, $|x+1| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(-1)| < \epsilon$. If i choose $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$, we have that $\frac{-3}{2}<x<\frac{-1}{2}$ and the only $x$ I have in EE that satifies the property is $x=-1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(-1)|=0 < \epsilon$. Hence f is cont at $-1$.

Secondly, f is continuous on the interval $[0,1]$ if and only if f is continuous at a point $x_0 \in [0,1]$. fix $x_0 \in [0,1]$, then for any given  $\epsilon >0$ I want to find a $\delta >0$  such that for all $x \in E,   |x-x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. My problem is I cant seem to find an appropriate $\delta$ that works for me. please guys help me. Thanks

Comment: Your proof that $f$ is continuous at $-1$ is correct. Why not try the same $\delta$ for $x_0\in[0,1]$?

Comment: That's my problem. I can t seems to choose an appropriate $\delta$

Comment: You want to show $f$ is continuous at $x_0\in[0,1]$. Choose $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$. Now if $x\in E$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$ we must have $x\in [0,1]$. So $f(x)=f(x_0)=2$ and hence $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0<\epsilon$.

Comment: for this choice of $\delta$, I am wondering if this works perfectly fine if choosing arbitrarily $x_0 =1$.  we get $x \in (\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})$ which  means that there are some $x$ outside the domain of the function. Please clarifications will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't that bother you for $x=-1$? :)  But you are not interested in $x$ outside the domain. All you have to show is that if $x$ is in the domain and $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$. So $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$ works for every point in the domain and every $\epsilon$.